# How to find the pairs of users that have bough the same product?

Tags: mysql

An online shop has three tables: User, Item, Buys.
Buys combines the IDs of User(s) and Item(s) they have purchased:

User:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Emma |
| 3 | Carl |

Item:

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Ball |
| 20 | Guitar |
| 30 | Book |

Buys:

| User | Item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 20 |

I have to come up with a query that lists, in two columns, paired names of Users that bought the same Item. It sounded simple at first but as of now I've been on this for almost three hours.

**Expected result:**

| User 1 | User 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |

This is what I got at the moment:

```
SELECT U1.name AS 'User 1', U2.name **AS** 'User 2'
FROM User U1, User U2
JOIN Buys B1 ON B1.user = id
JOIN Buys B2 ON B2.user = U2.id
WHERE** B1.item = B2.item
```

I tried other ways using subqueries, however it was a bit too confusing so I will not post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a self join of the table `Buys`:

```
SELECT b1.User User1, b2.User User2
FROM Buys b1 INNER JOIN Buys b2
ON b2.Item = b1.Item AND b2.User > b1.User
```

If you also want the names of the users you must join 2 copies of `Users` to the above query:

```
SELECT b1.User UserID1, u1.Name UserName1, 
       b2.User UserID2, u2.Name UserName2
FROM Buys b1 
INNER JOIN Buys b2 ON b2.Item = b1.Item AND b2.User > b1.User
INNER JOIN Users u1 ON u1.ID = b1.User
INNER JOIN Users u2 ON u2.ID = b2.User
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=da8323141ff3308d36ad03bf906918b0).

Comment: Yes this works great, Thank you!! I indeed needed the names, this is what I added to your code, without Joining the tables: SELECT U1.name User1, U2.name User2
FROM User U1, User U2, Buys b1 INNER JOIN Buys b2
ON b2.Item = b1.Item AND b2.User > b1.User
WHERE U1.id = b1.user AND U2.id = b2.user

Comment: @YrokKory You are joining the tables, but you use the syntax with `,` and WHERE clauses instead of the explicit JOIN syntax with ON clauses.